# Setting signal for SIGWINCH causes output on terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, signals

When I set up a signal handler for SIGWINCH that does nothing, resizing the terminal window causes a reverse `?` character to show up, get several of them as I resize the window around.   If I don't setup a signal handler, that doesn't happen.  Why is it doing that and How do I stop that?

More information: I dump what the chars were, when you start the first char is 0xFF, then 0xBF after that (always 0xBF), until you stop and start again, then repeats.

TIA

```
void sigwinchhandler(int signo)
{
}

struct sigaction sa, priorsa;
sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
sa.sa_flags = 0;
sa.sa_handler = sigwinchhandler;
sigaction(SIGWINCH, &sa, &priorsa);
// NOTE: priorsa.sa_handler==NULL, priorsa.sa_sigaction==NULL, priorsa.sa_flags==0
```

Comment: to detect resizing of the terminal window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix is to set:

`sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;`